# Why is my form inside my bootstrap modal col-md-6 by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website and tried to embed a form as a partial view inside a modal window. I succeeded in getting the form inside the modal, but it only appears on the left half of the modal body. Does anyone know a fix for this?

I never set the col-md-6 anywhere so there i no reason for it to appear this way. I even tried to exactly copy some modal examples from the internet that appeared to be correct, but i had the same problem.

**Modal window that the form is loaded in**:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="addLeverancierModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Leverancier toevoegen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Opslaan</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

**Modal form(partial view)**:

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Leveranciernummer</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="leveranciernummerInput" placeholder="Leveranciernumer">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Naam</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="leveranciernaamInput" placeholder="Naam">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Straatnaam</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="straatnaamInput" placeholder="Straatnaam">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Huisnummer</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="huisernummerInput" placeholder="Huisnummer">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Postcode</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="postcodeInput" placeholder="Postcode">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Plaatsnaam</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="plaatsnaamInput" placeholder="Plaatsnaam">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Land</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="landInput" placeholder="Land">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>VAT</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="vatInput" placeholder="VAT">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Telefoon</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="telefoonInput" placeholder="Telefoon">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="emailInput" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email extra</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="emailExtraInput" placeholder="Email extra">
</div>
</form>
```

**JQuery to load form inside modal:**

```
var GetLeverancierForm = function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseURL + '/AddLeverancier',
    success: function (data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
    }
});
}
```

**Base container all content is loaded in(all html files):**

```
    <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

Picture of how the modal appears:
[image: My modal that only has content on the left]

Comment: When you resize the window do the fields actually only ever take up half of the modal, or do they expand to fit it? It might just be that the default size for the inputs makes it look like it's split in half.

Comment: Offhand, it doesnt look like your `<form role="form">` has a closing tag like `</form>`, try adding that first

Comment: your missing `.container` around your code. `.container` followed by `.row`. Better if you have a live example of the code.

Comment: @Nofel the whole page including the modal is loaded inside a container. See the last code example. Is it still required that i place a container inside the modal-body?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Whoops! Accidentally did not include the closing tag in the post. However, in my code i do have it. Unfortunately that's not the problem

Comment: Show us the actual rendered html from "inspect element"

Comment: Something else is happening in your render, my guess would be invalid html somewhere, but we cant know till we see the rendered html, this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/21/ shows that the html you show here works fine

Comment: This here is all of the rendered html.
https://pastebin.com/xDmE3sR9

Comment: Your rendered html also appears to be fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/23/  are you certain that you dont have some CSS rule affecting this modal body? like `{width:50%}` somewhere?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I am 100% sure. I just started this project and only created 1 custom css file, which contains 2 lines: make the mouse a pointer when it hovers over a table row.
That's seriously the only custom css i created.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? as you can see in the fiddle, it works fine, there must be something different in your actual project

Comment: @DelightedD0D it's v3.3.7 (which is the defaul for a fresh asp.net mvc project)

Comment: @DelightedD0D as you see in this picture it seems to be at full width? weird

http://prntscr.com/f05wds

It also looks like it adds a margin

http://prntscr.com/f05wtp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142471/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-mick).

Answer (score -1):

Design your form like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

It would look like this :

[image]

Comment: The thing is that i do not want a horizontal form actually. I just want my form to use the full width

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why you feel that it solves the stated problem. (btw, it doesnt)